# Не могу понять что происходит с массивом

Tags: swift

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RestarauntsCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let restaurant =  (searchController.active) ? searchResultsArray[indexPath.row] : myRestaraunts[indexPath.row]

    cell.restarauntsImage.image = UIImage(data: restaurant.image)
    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurant.name
    cell.locationLabel.text = restaurant.location
    cell.typeLabel.text = restaurant.type
    cell.restarauntsImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.restarauntsImage.frame.size.height / 2
    cell.restarauntsImage.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.checkMarkImage.hidden = !restaurant.isVisited.boolValue

   // cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "head.png"))
    //cell.accessoryView = myRestaraunts[indexPath.row] ?  UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "head.png")): nil

    return cell
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку `Array index out of range`. Происходит при движении на `SearchController`

Спасибо.

Comment: В данном блоке кода не показано, как заполняются данными searchResultsArray и myRestaraunts. Ошибка именно в доступе к элементу массива которого нет.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, вероятнее всего находится в `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`, который вы не показали. Количество строк в этом методе, вероятно, отличается от количества элементов в одном из массивов `searchResultsArray` или `myRestaraunts`.

Answer (score 1):

Исключение, возникающее при попытке обращения к элементу массива или коллекции с индексом, который находится вне границ. Ваша ошибка кроется в одном из двух массивов `searchResultsArray` или `myRestaraunts`. То есть падает оно вот в этом месте:

```
searchResultsArray[indexPath.row] : myRestaraunts[indexPath.row]
```

Иными словами `indexPath.row` - выдает число, которое превышает максимально допустимое значение размерности одного из двух массивов (а возможно и двух). Вам необходимо проверить размерность массивов и по возможности исключить ситуацию:

> Array index out of range

в принципе, ошибка говорит сама за себя, дело осталось только в выяснении конкретного места ошибки. Либо в массиве вовсе нет элементов, либо их меньше этого числа (индекса, по которому обращаемся).

Answer (score 0):

Для полноты картины в вопрос нужно добавить вашу реализацию метода tableView:numberOfRowsInSection.

Скорее всего (т.к. падает на SearchController), этот метод устанавливает количество строк равное размеру массива myRestaraunts. Но поиск содержит лишь некоторое подмножество элементов из myRestaraunts, поэтому количество элементов в массиве searchResultsArray меньше, чем в массиве myRestaraunts. Отсюда и ошибка запроса элемента массива с индексом большим, чем количество элементов в этом массиве.

Поэтому метода источника данных, отвечающий за определение количества строк в таблице, скорее всего должен выглядеть так:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchController.active ? searchResultsArray.count : myRestaraunts.count
}
```